# Help with proof by contradiction

Tags: analysis

I'm relatively new with proofs and am trying to self-teach. I'm currently going through questions that unfortunately have no solutions... I've been doing well until I struck this one:

**If l, m, and n are consecutive integers, then 12 does not divide $l^2 + m^2 + n ^2 +1$.**

I know that proof by contradiction is  p and (not q) => C. So to start off, I assume that it IS divisible by 12 and I have $l$, $m=l+1$, n=$l+2$. Therefore $l^2 + m^2 + n ^2 +1 = 3l^2+6l+6 = 3(l^2+2l+2)$. This is as far as a got. Any help or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Now you have to show that 4 does not divide the expression in paranthesis

Comment: You are very close. Since $12 \mid l^2+m^2+n^2 +1$ it must be that $12 \mid 3(l^2+2l+2)$. So, $4$ must divide $l^2+2l+2$. Is there any value of $l$ to allow that?

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

Let us continue your work.

$$12|3 (l^2+2l+2)\implies $$
$$4|l^2+2l+2 \implies $$

$$2|l^2+2l+2 \implies $$
$$2|l \implies l=2p \implies $$
$$4|4p^2+4p+2 \implies 4|2$$

You can finish.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with "|" but I assume it means X is a factor of Y? How did you get from the second to third line? Thanks!

Comment: @4yourneed If $l^2+2l+2$ is divisible by 4 then surely it must also be divisible by 2, as it is even. In other words, if $4|l^2+2l+2$, then $2|l^2+2l+2$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$
l^2+2l+2=(l+1)^2+1
$$

Answer (score 1):

Lets try it in this way

Take $l=m-1,n=m+1$

Then the expression becomes $$(m-1)^2+m^2+(m+1)^2+1$$

Which reduces to $$3(m^2+1)$$

Now if $m$ is even then the expression in paranthesis is odd and not divisible by $4$

If $m$ is odd , then $m^2=8k+1$ and $m^2+1=8k+2$ which is not divisible by 4

So the work is done

Similar argument you can use in your expression

Hope it helps.....!!!!